# csv.writer prints "bytes" with prefix and quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-unicode

In Python 2 this code does what I'd expect:

```
import csv
import sys

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow([u'hello', b'world'])
```

It prints:

```
hello,world
```

But in Python 3, `bytes` are printed with a prefix and quotes:

```
hello,b'world'
```

Since CSV is a generic data interchange format, and since no system other than Python knows what `b''` is, I need to disable this behavior.  But I haven't figured out how.

Of course I could use `str.decode` on all the `bytes` first, but that is inconvenient and inefficient.  What I really want is either to write the literal bytes to the file, or pass an encoding (e.g. 'ascii') to `csv.writer()` so it knows how to decode any `bytes` objects it sees.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way of avoiding having to explictly convert the byte strings into unicode strings with the `csv` module in Python 3. In Python 2, they're implicitly converted to ASCII.

To make this easier you could effectively subclass `csv.writer` or wrap objects as shown below, which will make the process more convenient.

```
import csv

class CSV_Writer(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(*args, **kwrds)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.csv_writer, name)

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.csv_writer.writerow(str(v, encoding='utf-8') if isinstance(v, bytes) 
                                        else v for v in row)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)


with open('bytes_test.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = CSV_Writer(file)
    writer.writerow([u'hello', b'world'])
```

Comment: Bytes strings and unicode strings are two different types in Python 2 as well.  Python 2 just allows implicit conversion using the default `ascii` codec.

Answer (score 1):

`csv` writes text files and expects Unicode (text) strings in Python 3.

`csv` writes binary files and expects byte strings in Python 2, but allowed implicit encoding of Unicode strings to byte strings using the default `ascii` codec.  Python 3 does not allow implicit conversion, so you can't really avoid it:

```
#!python3
import csv
import sys
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(['hello', b'world'.decode()])
```